# How can i change the placeholderText color in QML TextField

Tags: qt, qml, textfield

I tried using the TextField Styled  but there was no effect on the placeholder text ,how do i change the color of placeholderText

Answer (score 4):

`TextField` has a property `placeholderTextColor` dedicated to the color:

With Qt Quick Controls 2 (requires at least Qt 5.12):

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
TextField {
    anchors.fill: parent
    placeholderText: "Here is a place holder"
    placeholderTextColor: "red"
}
```

With Qt Quick Controls 1:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
TextField {
      anchors.fill: parent
      style: TextFieldStyle {
          placeholderTextColor: "red"
      }
      placeholderText: "Here is a place holder"
}
```

Comment: this is the error i get :qrc:/main.qml:76 Cannot assign to non-existent property "placeholderTextColor"

Comment: @NokiasBonoloNeo Are you perhaps using QtQuick Controls 1? (this answer is for Controls 2)

Comment: i am using QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Comment: Hmm, this is the supporting document: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-textfield.html#placeholderTextColor-prop

Comment: is not there another way?

Comment: I've updated my answer with example for both versions of Qt Quick

Comment: Note the "This property was introduced in QtQuick.Controls 2.5 (Qt 5.12)." sentence in the docs. You need Qt 5.12 and the import has to be QtQuick.Controls 2.5.

Comment: placeholderText: "Search here"
Material.theme: Material.Dark